# Node.js performance

Tags: node.js, performance

Imagine, we got 2 simple classes (omitted export):

```
class SomeService {
  async func () {
    // some async function logic
    return value;
  }
}

class SomeController {
  constructor (service) {
    this.service = service;
  }
  async func () {
    const value = await this.service.func();
    // some controller-specific logic here
    return value;
  }
}
```

Also, we got simple function, that use this two classes in two ways.

Case one:

```
// require clasess

const somefunc = async () => {
  const controller = new SomeController(new SomeService());
  const value = await controller.func();
  return value;
}
module.exports = somefunc;
```

Case two:

```
// require clasess
const controller = new SomeController(new SomeService());

const somefunc = async () => {
  const value = await controller.func();
  return value;
}
module.exports = somefunc;
```

As far as i understand how node's `require` works in the first case `controller` will be created each time when the `somefunc` is called. In the second case `controller` is created only one time, when the file will be evaluated. What case is better and more importantly what should i read or lookup to understand why?

Comment: it's not about "which is better" but "which scope better models the problem you're trying to solve".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the answer depends on your use-case. You have to ask yourself if you need to recreate `SomeController` every time that the function is called or not. Another thing to also consider is whether `SomeController` relies on something async when being initialized. For instance, if the controller needs access to a database connection in its constructor, then you'd have to wait for the database connection to be established. In situations like that, you may have no choice but to initialize `SomeController` inside the function. As I said, there's no objective `better` in cases like this. It's all dependent on your use-case.